# ASIHTTPRequest - Setting to ignore cache/proxy

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest, cache-control, squid

I am using ASIHTTPRequest and pulling content from our server which has Squid cache on it.  It seems that ASIHTTPRequest is not getting the newest content version.

**How can I tell it to ignore the cache so that I can get the newest version? Or is there a better way to do this?**

The following is what I am using:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:serviceUrl];
[request setDownloadCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];
[request setCachePolicy:ASIAskServerIfModifiedCachePolicy|ASIFallbackToCacheIfLoadFailsCachePolicy];
[request setCacheStoragePolicy:ASICachePermanentlyCacheStoragePolicy];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:50.0];
[request addRequestHeader:@"CacheControl" value:@"no-cache"];
[request startSynchronous];
```

Comment: Looks like it needed to be: [request addRequestHeader:@"Cache-Control" value:@"no-cache"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Header should be:

```
CacheControl: reload
```

That should tell squid to fetch the request from the server, but that depends on the configuration of the squid server. Maybe this feature is disabled ?

Can you do a forced reload in a browser ?

I think no-cache just means that the server should not update it's cache.

Comment: if nothing else work you could add a get parameter to your request with the current time

Comment: no-cache is working well for me.  Here is what I read it does: http://palisade.plynt.com/issues/2008Jul/cache-control-attributes/